# Agrupar resultados de consultas

Tags: mysql, while, stored-procedures

A procedure abaixo faz uma consulta por dia entre as datas iniciais e final, sendo assim, ela trás várias consultas, há uma forma de agrupar todas as consultas geradas em apenas uma? E ainda, como eliminar os resultados vázios?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_get_balanco_entre_datas(IN data_ini DATETIME, IN data_fin DATETIME)
BEGIN
DECLARE dataini DATE;
DECLARE datafin DATE;

SET dataini = DATE(data_ini);
SET datafin = DATE(data_fin);

REPEAT

SELECT *
FROM saldo
WHERE DATE(data_mov_saldo) = DATE(dataini)
ORDER BY data_mov_saldo DESC
LIMIT 1;

SET dataini = DATE_ADD(dataini, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
UNTIL dataini > datafin END REPEAT;
END //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o operador [`BETWEEN`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm) para fazer consultas de intervalo de datas.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM saldo
WHERE DATE(data_mov_saldo) BETWEEN DATE(dataini) AND DATE(datafin) 
ORDER BY data_mov_saldo DESC
```

Dessa forma você pode eliminar o `REPEAT`.

#### Para pegar o último valor de cada dia, faça algo assim:

```
SELECT DATE(data_mov_saldo) as data_mov_saldo, valor
FROM 
(
  SELECT data_mov_saldo as data_mov_saldo, valor, 
         ( 
           CASE DATE(data_mov_saldo) 
           WHEN @curData 
           THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
           ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curData := DATE(data_mov_saldo) END
         ) + 1 AS rn
  FROM saldo, (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curData := '') r
  WHERE DATE(data_mov_saldo) BETWEEN DATE('2015-06-01') AND DATE('2015-06-30') 
  ORDER BY data_mov_saldo DESC
) result
WHERE result.rn = 2
```

### [SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04044/7/0)

#### Explicação

Antes de tudo preciso criar variáveis na consulta que vai me possibilitar fazer um equivalente ao [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) junto ao `PARTITION BY`.

```
(SELECT @curRow := 0, @curData := '') r
```

Dentro do `CASE` a gente vai incrementando a linha enquanto a data for no mesmo dia (`DATE`) independente da hora. É o `@curData` que me permite fazer esse agrupamento de contadores.

```
( 
   CASE DATE(data_mov_saldo) 
   WHEN @curData 
   THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
   ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curData := DATE(data_mov_saldo) END
) + 1 AS rn
```

Por fim eu ordeno `data_mov_saldo DESC` para pegar o último registro do dia e no `SELECT` de fora faço `result.rn = 2` para pegar apenas o **1° registro** de cada agrupamento.

Comment: Não é possível, tentei dessa forma, mas são gerados vários registros por dia e necessito pegar apenas o ultimo de cada dia. Por isso fiz dessa forma.

Comment: Pera ai que a gente resolve isso

Comment: @Mamedio Atualizei minha resposta, as datas eu fixei no between, você pode alterar conforme seus parâmetros.

Comment: Coloquei explicações também :)

Comment: Cara, eu não consegui entender...A procedure já trás o  ultimo registro de cada dia, o repeat é para rodar entre as datas, não consegui implementar aqui sua resposta :s

Comment: @Mamedio Com o `select` que te mostrei tu só executa ele uma única vez, não precisa do repeat. Como você quer exibir o resultado final?

Comment: Cara, ÓTIMO, to conseguindo aqui, você salvou minha pele hehehehe Muito obrigado, vou deixar bonitinho e dou um retorno!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25087/discussion-between-mamedio-and-maicon-carraro).